# How to define vertices in absolute values?

Tags: c, opengl

I'm taking my first steps into OpenGL land and I'm having trouble with **Vertex** declaration. Meaning, I've only successfully defined vertices by using relative size to the window as coordinates (those 0.25 mean 500*0.25=125). This seems unintuitive.

How do you define vertices without relative values?

```
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void displayInit(void) {
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

void display(void) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Select a drawing color
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    // Draw a square
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2f(-0.25, -0.25); // start from -1/4 window w, -1/4 window h
        glVertex2f(-0.25, 0.25);  // add point 1/4 window h up from center
        glVertex2f(0.25, 0.25);
        glVertex2f(0.25, -0.25);
    glEnd();

    // Display the whole drawing on screen
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // Initialize with a window
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);

    // Display first screen
    displayInit();

    // Enter the display loop
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

This is how the graphic looks

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `glScale`?

Comment: No I haven't, I'm not aware of what that is. Could you elaborate?

Comment: the first hit that came up on Google: http://www.swiftless.com/tutorials/opengl/scaling.html. Add `glScalef(1f/500, 1f/500, 1f/500);` to your init or drawing routine. The `500` is your window width, and if I remember correctly you can query for its value.

Answer (score 2):

In old versions of OpenGL, this was done with the now deprecated matrix manipulation functions like glOrtho. (In fact, your use of glBegin, glVertex, and glEnd is also deprecated...)

If you don't mind using deprecated functionality, look into glPushMatrix, glPopMatrix, glScale, glRotate, and glTranslate, and you will start to get the idea for how to define different coordinate systems. Also look into glMatrixMode and know the difference between your projection matrix and your modelview matrix. Your projection matrix will be the one to apply glOrtho, or possibly gluPerspective if you want it to 'look right' (far away objects are smaller).

But, if you want to use the modern API, you will have to apply matrix transformations to your data yourself using a library like [glm](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.4/index.html).

Here's an excellent [tutorial](http://duriansoftware.com/joe/An-intro-to-modern-OpenGL.-Chapter-1%3a-The-Graphics-Pipeline.html) on how to do so.

Comment: Wow, a really useful source of info! If you could just add an example, from the modern API, of how you would do this - it would be an insta-accept.

Comment: @MorganWilde Unfortunately, an example from the modern API is non-trivial to construct, which is why I linked the tutorial which has examples and explains them in enough detail to get started.

Comment: Those functions you mentions are not matrix transformation functions, but matrix *manipulation* functions (the actual transformation happens later, when the vertex is actually multiplied with the matrices). Also most relevant for OP would be a projection that maps view space XY into viewport pixel space.